# thrust::complex with thrust reduce does not compile

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I have been trying to implement some code requiring to call reduce on thrust::complexes, and the compiler fires me an error saying:

> cannot pass an argument with a user-provided copy-constructor to a device-side kernel launch

Here is the code:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/complex.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace thrust;

void exec() {
    auto v = std::vector<complex<double>>({1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0});
    auto complexZero = complex<double>();
    device_vector<complex<double>> devA(v);
    thrust::reduce(devA.begin(), devA.end(), complexZero, plus<complex<double>>());    
}
int main() {
    exec();
}
```

[CUDA 9.2 with g++]

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: What version of CUDA are you using? And what host compiler?

Comment: I am using cuda 9.2 and compile it with the line `nvcc test.cu -std=c++14 -arch=sm_61 --device-c`

For the host compiler, I'm not sure I understand your question, the only compiler I use in this example is nvcc

Comment: nvcc isn't a compiler. It uses a host compiler (gcc, clang or the visual C++ compiler) to do most of the work. Which one are you using?

Comment: Oh, okay ! (I'm still an extreme beginner at cuda). I checked, and the host compiler is gcc

Comment: This appears to be a defect in the CUDA 9.2 version of thrust.  Your code compiles cleanly for me on CUDA 9.1, gcc 4.8.5, RHEL 7.x, substituting `-std=c++11` for `-std=c++14` in the compile command line.  I've filed an internal defect with NVIDIA.  You're welcome to file a thrust issue or report a bug at developer.nvidia.com.  I don't have any further information at this time.  OK it looks like you've already filed a thrust issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed as of CUDA 10.0.

Source: I'm the Thrust maintainer.

Answer (score 2):

This would appear to be some sort of regression in the version of thrust shipped in CUDA 9.2. The code you posted compiles correctly in CUDA 9.1 and earlier.

The issue appears to have been raised with both NVIDIA and the thrust developers.

[This post added from comments as a community wiki entry to get the question of the unanswered queue. Feel free to edit it as more information regarding a resolution becomes available]

Comment: It is indeed a regression. Link to the github issue: https://github.com/thrust/thrust/issues/928